# Determine time taken for light to travel between points through circular, sub-wavelength aperture

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, refraction, mathematics, models

#### Background

I'm working on numerically modeling some physical phenomenon using electromagnetics simulation software. I have a particular physical setup modeled, wherein I've noticed some non-intuitive behavior. I'd like to model that setup theoretically, so as to better understand the behavior (and verify my results).

#### Problem

Light of wavelength $\lambda$ (on the order of tens of $\textrm{cm}$) is incident upon a long cylindrical hole of diameter $d$ (potentially less than $\lambda$) in a semi-transparent medium (e.g. ice) with refractive index $n>1$. The light source is located several wavelengths directly above the aperture and the (flat) surface of the medium. The interior of the hole and the space above the surface of the medium can be assumed to be a vacuum (i.e. $n=1$).

Suppose the source emits a light pulse. **How do I find the time taken for the light pulse to travel between a point $A$ and a point $B$, both of which are located within and coaxial with the cylindrical hole?**

I would have naively assumed that the transit time for a hole diameter of $\frac{1}{2}d$ would be half of that for a diameter of $0$ (e.g. transmission purely through the semi-transparent medium). Instead, I find that the transmission time plateaus for small $d$, then drops drastically and is very near that for transmission in pure vacuum, even when $d<<\lambda$.

[image]